# How do I pass data from one operator to another

Tags: python, airflow

I made a custom airflow operator, this operator takes an input and the output of this operator is on XCOM.

What I want to achieve is to call the operator with some defined input, parse the output as Python callable inside the Branch Operator and then pass the parsed output to another task that calls the same operator tree:

```
CustomOperator_Task1 = CustomOperator(
    data={
        'type': 'custom',
        'date': '2017-11-12'
    },
    task_id='CustomOperator_Task1',
    dag=dag)

data = {}
def checkOutput(**kwargs):
    result = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='CustomOperator_Task1')

    if result.success = True:
        data = result.data
        return "CustomOperator_Task2"
    return "Failure"

BranchOperator_Task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='BranchOperator_Task ',
    dag=dag,
    python_callable=checkOutput,
    provide_context=True,
    trigger_rule="all_done")

CustomOperator_Task2 = CustomOperator(
    data= data,
    task_id='CustomOperator_Task2',
    dag=dag)

CustomOperator_Task1 >> BranchOperator_Task >> CustomOperator_Task2
```

In task `CustomOperator_Task2` I would want to pass the parsed data from `BranchOperator_Task`. Right now it is always empty `{}`

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you include snippets your custom operator? Does the `execute()` method return the output value to push to XCom or does it call `xcom_push()` explicitly?

Comment: it does not do xcom_push explicitly, however I believe that the return from an operator is pushed to xcom anyways (by airflow) and I can read it my BranchOperator_Task's python_callable.

Comment: I got it to work by extending my custom operator to expect a callable function to retrieve the data, I pass a function to data parameter and then the function can decide what to return.

Answer (score 2):

I see your issue now. Setting the `data` variable like you are won't work because of how Airflow works. An entirely different process will be running the next task, so it won't have the context of what `data` was set to.

Instead, `BranchOperator_Task` has to push the parsed output into another XCom so `CustomOperator_Task2` can explicitly fetch it.

```
def checkOutput(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    result = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='CustomOperator_Task1')

    if result.success:
        ti.xcom_push(key='data', value=data)
        return "CustomOperator_Task2"
    return "Failure"

BranchOperator_Task = BranchPythonOperator(
    ...)

CustomOperator_Task2 = CustomOperator(
    data_xcom_task_id=BranchOperator_Task.task_id,
    data_xcom_key='data',
    task_id='CustomOperator_Task2',
    dag=dag)
```

Then your operator might look something like this.

```
class CustomOperator(BaseOperator):

    @apply_defaults 
    def __init__(self, data_xcom_task_id, data_xcom_key, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data_xcom_task_id = data_xcom_task_id
        self.data_xcom_key = data_xcom_key
    def execute(self, context):
        data = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=self.data_xcom_task_id, key=self.data_xcom_key)
        ...
```

Parameters may not be required if you just want to hardcode them. It depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

As your comment suggests, the return value from your custom operator is None, therefore your xcom_pull should expect to be empty.
Please use xcom_push explicitly, as the default behavior of airflow could change over time.

Comment: The return value of the custom operator is not 'None' :-( it is an object which when I print in 'checkOutput' is displayed correctly.

Comment: I know pass a function to the custom operator (changed the custom operator) that function now decides what to return, for now it is reading from xcom and returning it. BTW I do think it is a good idea to do a explicit push to xcom. I adapted custom operator for it